# How can Google Analytics report a high bounce rate and average time on page in minutes? What is the difference?

Tags: google-analytics, visitors, bounce-rate, session

Some pages in my website(s) have low/high bounce rate but the Avg. Time on Page is more than 4 minutes
**can anyone explain to me why the bounce rate is still high?**

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide more details? Which metrics are you trying to figure out? You ask about average time on page, but you have a screenshot about average session duration. You have highlighted pages/session on your screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Google](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009409?hl=en), a bounce rate is defined as:

> Bounce rate is single-page sessions divided by all sessions, or the
>   percentage of all sessions on your site in which users viewed only a
>   single page and triggered only a single request to the Analytics
>   server.

Given this definition, your session duration does not impact your bounce rate number.  Only, how many pages the user viewed on your site, or additional requests to Analytics.

So, your users could spend four minutes on a given page, and have their question fully answered, but not visit any other pages on your site.  Using the above definition, this would be considered a bounce.

Answer (score 0):

This tool (Google Analytics) is created for millions different businesses, and as we now that every business is different in their own way you can't expect it to be suited for your business, so you can just plug it in an wait for results. The beauty and the challenge is to configure it right to get meaningful data. **Bounce** is calculated on **session** level, session end in : **30 min** (by default, can be configured), **End of the day** (time zone which is set in GA account), **When Acquisition Campaign changes**, end more end more. All of that affect the bounce rate. And much more things for example if your page is too long, have a lot of reading material maybe not possible to read in 30 minutes that is a bounce as well.

And avg. time on page is by default calculated (time difference between 2 hits)

My advice is that you need To create new marketing/tracking plan go briefly through your site see where you can add some events, goals etc. If the page is too long add a scroll tracking or timer trigger, or even combine them (example). I mean the beauty is that you can track whatever you imagine to track, but the point is to track what is relevant for your business.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate that, thanks for the very good input!

Answer (score 0):

Bounce rate is single-page sessions divided by all sessions, or the percentage of all sessions on your site in which users viewed only a single page and triggered only a single request to the Analytics server.

Average session duration is: total duration of all sessions (in seconds) / number of sessions.
Individual session duration is calculated differently depending on whether there are engagement hits on the last page of a session. [Read more](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1006253?hl=en)

Both of these metrics are different from each other in terms of engagement and interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Average session duration navigates between two requests timestamp for the next page views. So the average amount of time a user spends on the page on your website known as Average Time.

Bounce Rate just others thing means visitors how much time spends on your website. It means the duration of the website to users enter and exit timestamp known as bounce rate. The bounce rate of website is always minimum.